# Как построить кусочную функцию в matplotlib (python)?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
def s_similar(x):
    if x < a:
        return 0
    elif a <= x <= ((a + b) / 2):
        return (2 * ((x - a) ** 2)) / ((b - a) ** 2)
    elif (a + b) / 2 <= x <= b:
        return 1 - (2 * ((x - a) ** 2)) / ((b - a) ** 2)
    else:
        return 1
```

есть такая кусочная функция

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)
y = np.vectorize(func.s_similar)

graph1 = plt.plot(x, y)
```

и такой код, который совсем не работает
есть ли вообще возможность построения кусочной функции, средствами numpy и matpotlib, чтобы не искать дискретную функцию вручную ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы после `np.vectorize()` ваша функция правильно отрабатывала - ее придется немного переписать:

```
def s_similar2(x):
    if x < a:
        return 0
    elif (a <= x) and (x <= ((a + b) / 2)):
        return (2 * ((x - a) ** 2)) / ((b - a) ** 2)
    elif ((a + b) / 2 <= x) and (x <= b):
        return 1 - (2 * ((x - a) ** 2)) / ((b - a) ** 2)
    else:
        return 1

y = np.vectorize(s_similar2, otypes=[float])
```

проверка:

```
np.random.seed(31415)
a,b = np.random.randint(100, size=2)
x = np.random.randint(100, size=100)

print(sum(s_similar(i) for i in x) == sum(s_similar2(i) for i in x) == y(x).sum())
# True
```

кроме того [np.vectorize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) возвращает ссылку на "векторизированную" функцию. Поэтому надо вызывать `y(x)` вместо `y`

Попробуйте так:

```
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)
y = np.vectorize(s_similar2, otypes=[float])

a,b = 5,10
graph1 = plt.plot(x, y(x))
```

А еще лучше попробовать написать свою векторизированную функцию:

```
def f(x):
    return np.where(x < a,
                    0,
                    np.where((a <= x) & (x <= ((a + b) / 2)),
                             (2 * ((x - a) ** 2)) / ((b - a) ** 2),
                              np.where(((a + b) / 2 <= x) & (x <= b),
                                       1 - (2 * ((x - a) ** 2)) / ((b - a) ** 2),
                                       1)
                    )
            )
```

проверка:

```
In [97]: f(x).sum() == y(x).sum()
Out[97]: True
```

Выглядит немного уродливо, но на больших массивах должно давать хороший прирост производительности.

```
In [94]: x = np.random.randint(10**5, size=10**5)

In [95]: %timeit y(x)
503 ms ± 654 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [96]: %timeit f(x)
5.51 ms ± 9.17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

График:

```
a,b = -5, 5
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 20)
graph1 = plt.plot(x, f(x))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, все решилось